# Fastest way to embed watermark on 10 min video in android or windows10?

Tags: video, watermark

I downloaded some win10 and android apps for watermarking video but they take for ever in both devices. Like minimum 1 hour for a 10 min video to be watermarked.

I know this is heavy work for the dear machines, but is there a hack for this?

The watermark is text onto the entire length of the video.

Thanks for any tips. x

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any test figures for different approaches so I suspect you may have to try different approaches and judge yourself. As you say, mobile devices do not have a lot of horsepower for this type of operation, as a rule.

As a benchmark I would suggest you use ffmpeg via a wrapper library and possibly experiment with different ffmpeg parameters also.

The wrapper libraries effectively allow the command line ffmpeg to be executed from within a program or app in the case of mobile devices.

The following are commonly used ffmpeg wrapper libraries:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java (for Android)
- https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg (iOS and Android)

You can find many example of using ffmpeg syntax to add watermarks to videos if you search. You can see some examples in the ffmpeg documentation in the section looking at applying overlays using 'filters: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-87

The simplest example is:

> overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10